# Storing elements into an array

Tags: arrays, dart, flutter

Currently I am self-leaning dart, mainly app development with flutter. I'm having the problem of storing elements into a string array, getting the array from another class and successfully display. My goal is just to build a simple app that ask 3 question and displays them in a very fun way!!

```
class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget
{
  @override
  SecondPageState createState() => new SecondPageState();
}

class SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage>
{
  final TextEditingController controller = new TextEditingController();
  int counter = 0;
  var ask = ["What is your name?", "How old are you?", "What is your favorite hobby?"];
  var results = ["","",""];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Tell us about yourself"), backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange),
      body: new Container(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: new Center(
          child: new Column(
             mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Text(ask[counter], style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0,  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              new TextField(
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Type Here"
                ),
                onSubmitted: (String str)
               {
                 setState(()
                 {
                   results[counter] = ask[counter]; //Assigning 
                   if(counter < 2)
                   {
                     counter = counter + 1;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                     counter = 0;
                   }
                 });
               },
              ),
              new IconButton(
                padding: new EdgeInsets.only(right: 50.0),
                icon: new Icon(Icons.library_books, size: 70.0, color:   Colors.blueAccent),
                  onPressed: ()     {Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/ThirdPage");}
              ),
            ]
          )
        )
      )
    );
  }
}

class ThirdPageState extends State<ThirdPage>
{
  SecondPageState _second = new SecondPageState();

  // ignore: unnecessary_getters_setters
  SecondPageState get second => _second;

  // ignore: unnecessary_getters_setters, avoid_return_types_on_setters
  void set second(SecondPageState second) {
    _second = second;
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {

    //_second.results[0] = "christopher";
    return new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Your Biography"),    backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange),
      body: new Container(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: new Center(
          child: new Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              new MyCard(
                  tittle: new Text(second.results[0], style: new     TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 25.0
                  )),
                  icon: new Icon(Icons.favorite, size: 40.0, color: Colors.redAccent)
              ),
              new MyCard(
                  tittle: new Text(second.results[1], style: new TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 25.0
                  )),
                  icon: new Icon(Icons.local_pizza, size: 40.0, color: Colors.brown)
              ),
              new MyCard(
                  tittle: new Text(second.results[2], style: new TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 25.0
                  )),
                  icon: new Icon(Icons.visibility, size: 40.0, color:     Colors.blue)
          )
        ]
      )
    )
  )
);
```

}
}

Answer (score 1):

Rather than calling `Navigator.pushNamed`, you should call `Navigator.push`. This will allow you to pass arguments to your `ThirdPage` constructor.

```
Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute<Null>(
  builder: (context) => new ThirdPage(results: results);
));
```

You should store the result `List` as a final member on `ThirdPage` and access it in `ThirdPageState` as `widget.results`.

Generally you should have not have `SecondPageState` storing a direct reference to `ThirdPageState` as a member variable. While it's possible for a State to get a reference to another state, you'd want to use `GlobalKey` and call `currentState`, and it's much more maintainable to just pass the data as constructor arguments if you can.